# Vaadin's ComboBox in Grid not showing dropdown on click

Tags: combobox, vaadin, dropdown

I am running Vaadin 8, and have a TreeGrid with a column setup with combo box for editing. Unfortunately when I click on a combo on a row it momentarily opens and closes the dropdown, pretty much not allowing me to see the combo choices, however I can still type text in the combo and only then the dropdown appears (combo has few sample values in it). I noticed when my session expires (and the server is not connected) I am able to get the dropdown to open.

[image]

Here is my code snippet adding such a column:

```
tg.addComponentColumn( r -> { 

    ComboBox<String> labelsCb = new ComboBox<>();

    labelsCb.setNewItemProvider( new NewItemProvider<String>() {

        @Override
        public Optional<String> apply( String t ) {

            return Optional.of( t );
        }
    } ); 

    labelsCb.setDataProvider( labelsDp  );

    labelsCb.setHeight( LABEL_COMBO_HEIGHT + "px" );
    labelsCb.setWidth( LABEL_COMBO_WIDTH_PX + "px" );

    labelsCb.addSelectionListener( event -> {

        r.setLabel( event.getValue() );
    });

    return labelsCb;

} ).setCaption( LABEL ).setWidth( LABEL_COMBO_WIDTH_PX * 1.40 );
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the reason - my combo column was interfering with TreeGrid's expander column (first on the left) - once I made it second column it started working. It is a bug with TreeGrid I believe, but this one is a decent workaround.